# set value to hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, hidden-field

I know this question has been asked a lot.  I've searched everywhere.  I'm trying to set the value of a hidden input so I can submit it.  My jquery is linked.

here is my form:

```
<form id="selectedMovie" action="index.php" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" id="tester" name="tester" value="fifty" style="display:none;"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my javascript:

```
function selectVideo( title ){
    alert("" + 21);//works fine
    alert( $('input[name=tester]').val() );//tried
    alert( $('input#tester' ).val() );//tried
    //and a few other things.
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: why are you using `style=display:none` instead of `input type='hidden'` ?

Comment: Exactly how is it failing? Do you get an error message?

Comment: where is your hidden field and where are you calling the JS function

Comment: it is jquery ? 
`$('#tester').val('VALUE')`

Comment: What are you setting the value to? You haven't told us what you want to set it to.

Comment: It's unclear when your js is getting called.  It could be getting called before the input elements are ready.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works with out any changes

http://jsfiddle.net/zWn9h/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use hidden input element instead of display none.

Comment: The question is about setting the value, not hiding the element.

Answer (score 1):

To set the value to input box in jQuery you will have to use:

```
$('#tester').val('your_value');
```